# java.util.Timer or a While loop in a SwingWorker thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, while-loop, swingworker

In another question I posted recently I was suggested to use a java.util.Timer in the SwingWorker instead of a while loop. The tasks in the SwingWorker are supposed to run every 10 seconds.

From my understanding, java.util.Timer creates a background thread (run()) to perform tasks.

If I use the java.util.Timer in the SwingWorker thread, isn't it inefficient to create another thread (Timer) in a thread (SwingWorker)?

Please take a look at my two examples below and let me know which one is the correct one, or if none of the two are correct what else I should use (and please provide me with a short sample code if possible)? Thank you

**Example 1 - using java.util.Timer**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Example1 extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {

        int delay = 10000;//Delay for 10 seconds

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String database = "";

                //PARSE THE SQL DATABASE

                publish(database);//UPDATE THE GUI

            }
        }, delay);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> s) {
        //UPDATE THE GUI
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - using While loop**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Example2 extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {

        while (!this.isCancelled()) {

            String database = "";

            //PARSE THE SQL DATABASE

            publish(database);//UPDATE THE GUI

            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait(10000);//Wait 10 seconds
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> s) {
        //UPDATE THE GUI
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer is deprecated, fundamentally flawed and should not be used for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing that `SwingWorker` is doing is to launch a timer then it's useless indeed. Just spawn the timer from the UI thread and use `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` to update the GUI from the timer.

An even better alternative is [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, but let us assume I decided to go with a timer. Which is more correct to use from the UI thread: the javax.swing.Timer or java.util.Timer?

Comment: @jadrijan: It depends. If you are doing long computations or I/Os that don't use the GUI (like db access) use `java.util.Timer` + specific functions to update the GUI at the end. If all the actions of the timer are just updating the GUI use `javax.swing.Timer`. The difference between them is that the code of `javax.swing.Timer` is executed on the GUI thread.

Comment: Oh cool, thank you so much for explaining this to me in plain English. Honestly, I couldn't understand their differences from the examples I have come across due to wording (I am an ESL speaker :) ). Thank you again for explaining it nicely.

Comment: Tudor if you can answer one more question regarding the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. It is my first time using it and I do not know what the int corePoolSize is that I need to give its constructor. I only want 1 Job scheduled.

Comment: @jadrijan: Then use 1. That tells it how many background threads to create.